# Help resolving particular solution to recurrence relation?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, homogeneous-equation

$a_n=5a_{n-1} - 6_{n-2} + 4^n + 2n + 3$ for $n>=2$ , $a0 = 5, a1 = 19.$

I get the general solution

$ c_n = C_12^n+C_23^n.$

For a particular solution in the form $pn = An + B + C4^n$; we have

$An + B + C4^n = 5(A(n − 1) + B + C4n−1)
− 6(A(n − 2) + B + C4n−2) + 4n + 2n + 3$

But how do we get this:

$An + B + C4^n = −An + 7A − B + 14C4^{n−2} + 4^n + 2n + 3$

and therefore this:

$2An − 7A + 2B + 2C4^{n−2} = 2n + 3 + 16 × 4^{n−2}$

I don't understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the *principle of superposition of solutions; find particular solutions of
$$a_n=5a_{n-1} - 6_{n-2} + 4^n\quad (\text{resp. }{} + 2n,  {}+ 3)$$
then add these particular solutions.

*Example for $4^n$:*

A particular solution will have the form $a_n=C 4^n$. It is indeed a solution if
$$C4^n=5C4^{n-1}-6C4^{n-2}+4^n\iff 16C=20C-6C+16\iff C=8.$$

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example to get me on the right track? It isn't homework or an assignment. It was just a question posed in my lecture that I didn't fully understand.

Comment: I've added the case of $4^n$. As you see, it's just a matter of identification.

Comment: Thanks. Forgive me because I took uni maths 2 years ago and I am stupid but...How did you end up getting 20C - 6C + 16?

Comment: Factored out $4^{n-2}$ from both sides of the equation.